# Google calendar RRULE fails when updating but not when initially creating calendar entry

Tags: google-calendar-api, rrule

I already have an event entry that I created from my custom calendar with the following RRULE

```
FREQ=WEEKLY;DTSTART=20201203T090000;INTERVAL=2;BYDAY=TH;EXDATE:20201203T090000
```

When I update the event without changing the rrule I get an error

Error Message: Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "invalid", "message": "Invalid recurrence rule." } ], "code": 400, "message": "Invalid recurrence rule." } }

The only thing I can think of is that this rrule has dates in the past. Can anyone confirm that this would be the issue?

Comment: When you use the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get), setting `fields` to `recurrence`: what does the response exactly look like?

Answer (score 1):

`FREQ=WEEKLY;DTSTART=20201203T090000;INTERVAL=2;BYDAY=TH;EXDATE:20201203T090000` is not a valid recurrence rule. With all the invalid parts removed the rule would look like this:

```
FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=2;BYDAY=TH
```

`DTSTART` and `EXDATE` are separate properties.

Comment: `DTSTART` and `EXDATE` can be used within `RRULE` for Google Calendar API, it is just about getting the right syntax, which is different depending on the event parameters, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170070/google-calendar-api-rrule-and-exdate).

Comment: @ziganotschka can you show a working example to back this claim? [Google's Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#recurrence) is pretty clear about that. It says `Note that DTSTART and DTEND lines are not allowed in this field;` and refers to [RFC 5545](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545) regarding the format of each of the lines in the array.